# Why do I get this error: System.ArgumentNull Exception: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connection String') ASP.NET Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

Tools: Visual Studio 2019, Asp.net core 5.0 (AnyCpu), Windows 7 x64

I'm developing a small app and if I start it from VS or click on it it works fine but, the problem arises when I start it from `cmd.exe`.

In this case it gives me this error:

> System.ArgumentNull Exception: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connection String')

What's missing in this code?

The `startup.cs` is:

```cs
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDataDbContext>(options =>
             options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DATAconnection")));
        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```

The `appsettings.json` is:

```json
    "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-CORE;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "DATAconnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-DATA;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

  }
```

[image: Error screenshot from the app console]

Comment: FYI, Windows 7 has been completely unsupported for well over a year now; it's long past time to change operating system.

Comment: I know but have no intention of using Win10. How can i make this work on Win7?

Comment: *"How can i make this work on Win7?"* I never said the reason it isn't working is *because* you're using Windows 7, just that getting off that operating system needs to be a priority. *"I know but have no intention of using Win10."* is, with respect, a foolish stance; you've been getting no security updates for over a year now and you will find yourself vulnerable at some point. As a developer, as well, you'll find more and more new tools unavaible to you; including many recent versions of SQL Server (which will not run on Windows 7).

Comment: I'm using this on my internal Lan network on an old pc which doesn't support win10, for personal use, there's no risk of security breaches, nor updates are necessary. Could you kindly explain how can i make this work?

Comment: @Larnu Please, do not comment on questions what OP has not asked. We all know about W7 and we all may have our reasons to stick with it. OK?

Comment: No, @Arvo , I will continue to remind people when they are using unsupported software. We *may* have reason, but the OP has not given any in the question, and  it staggers me how many people have no idea that their software is unsupported... People *need* be educated when their systems are vulnerable. If you really feel so strongly that such things should not be commented on, I would suggest posting a question on [meta]; I'll be happy to post an answer on  my reasons why.

Comment: @Larnu This is simple netiquette thing - answer to (or comment the) question asked, not  promote your views (even if they are correct). Sure you may tell about unsupported software, but only as a side note, not as the main comment content - unless specific problem is caused by old software itself of course.

Comment: Again, I disagree, @Arvo. When/if I see the question in [meta] I'll post an answer, as we're off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason may be that the `DefaultConnection` has a null value in some other configuration provider. ASP.Net has multiple configuration providers and they are checked in the following order (with the last one taking precedence over others). So, in this sequence, the appsettings.json comes the last to look for.

1. appsettings.json file
2. appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json file
3. local User Secrets
4. Environment Variables
5. Command Line Arguments

So if there is an environment variable or secret named `DefaultConnection` then that would take a precedence. I am guessing you have that defined somewhere in one of these providers.

Comment: I already checked there is no other point where "DefaultConnection" can be found . As a further try, i created a new "default" app and the error i get is the same. What could be the problem?

Comment: Not sure if it is something specific to Windows7 as you are able to run the app from VS but not from commandline.
Try passing the connection string via command-line as ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection="Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-CORE;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

Comment: With this configuration :               services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>options =>options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection="Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-CORE;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true")));            i get an error: The name 'DefaultConnection' does not exist in the current context.   How and where should i insert or use it?

Comment: No, not in code. I meant to pass the connection string via commandline when you run your code from commandline. For example when using dotnet CLI: 
dotnet run ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection="Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-CORE;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

Comment: **It works without problems.**  PM> dotnet run --project MyApp ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection="Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-CORE;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
Building...
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

Comment: That means most probably there is some environment variable or secret already defined. You can check Windows 7 environment variables with the 'env' command or something similar.

Comment: User variables => Path: %USERPROFILE%\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin                                                                                            System Variables => Path: ...C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;...

Comment: Ok. I now have no idea what problem you are facing exactly so I give up. If you think my earlier answer has helped you, you can upvote or accept it. Thanks..

Comment: Thank you to everyone for every advise. I'll format the Pc and start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check whether your environment is Development or other environment in **launchsettings.json** file.

[image]

If it is development then it will look for Connection string in **appsettings.Development.json** file and not in appsettings.json file.

Have you checked in your DbContext file that you are passing a valid constructor with options parameter like the following?

```
  public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions options):base(options)
    {
        
    }
```

Comment: launchsettings.json was as in your screenshot, i changed it to production, on appsettings.Development.json i added the database connection string, but still there's no change. I published the app to see if it worked but it didn't.

Comment: public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }

Comment: Please check if you are adding identity in startup.cs file.
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>()..

Comment: services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

Answer (score 0):

I've come to the conclusion that, there seems to be a "connectionString" bug, on Visual Studio or .Net Core.

**This worked for me:**

Startup.cs ->

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connectionString = "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=aspnet-CORE;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```

**Some explanations :**

**a. To be covered on every situation i have left both the connection Strings on purpose.

b. This means that, if i call the "APP.exe" at system startup or though *.bat file,
it will call the manually injected "connectionString".

c. Otherwise, if i double click on it, it will use the "DefaultConnection" from appsettings.json, as the default connection.**

Hope it helps someone save some headaches.

Comment: Please show appsettings file , I think something wrong with that

Comment: {
    "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-CORE;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "DATAconnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-DATA;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
   },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}